# Trying to use ExecuteScalar , and get " Specified cast is not valid " error

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm trying to get product price by using product name.  Below is the function I am using.

```
public int GetProductPrice(string ProductName)
{
    cnn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ProductPrice FROM Products WHERE ProductName ='" + ProductName + "'", cnn);
    int price = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    return price;
}
```

Now I keep getting this error `Specified cast is not valid`, and I don't know why. Can someone help me ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection. Read. Learn.

Comment: dont use ExecuteScalar() in this situation - what happens if you have several products with the same name ...

Comment: Yea i know it but every product have another name (complitly diffrent)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly, you should use parameterized SQL instead of putting the parameter directly into the SQL. Also, you should use a `using` statement to close the command - and connection - when you're done. Oh, and create a new `SqlConnection` for each operation. So something like:

```
public int GetProductPrice(string productName)
{
    // Quite possibly extract the connection creation into a separate method
    // to call here.
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(...))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(
            "SELECT ProductPrice FROM Products WHERE ProductName = @ProductName",
            conn))
        {
            command.AddParameter("@ProductName", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                   .Value = productName;
            object price = command.ExecuteScalar();
            // And you'd do the casting here
        }
    }
}
```

Next, we don't know the type of the `ProductPrice` field. It could be that you're getting a `long` returned, or perhaps it's `decimal`. The simplest way to find out is just to use:

```
object tmp = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

... and then look in the debugger. Also look at the type of the field in the database - that should really tell you what to expect. Have a look at the [`SqlDbType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx) enumeration for mappings between the two.

Comment: well i cant belive it , the field ProdcutPrice was Nvarchar  , change it to int and everything works great, thanks

Comment: @user2120874: But please take the rest of the answer into consideration too - otherwise you're open to SQL injection attacks and all kinds of problems.

Comment: well i will take it for my other projects , but this is a school project so they dont try to SQLI me .
Thanks for the help

Comment: @user2120874 - "this is a school project so they dont try to SQLI me" You'd be surprised. I would. :)

Comment: @user2120874: You might get better marks if you show your teacher that you preventing hackers taking over the database in your project. If I were a teacher, I'd mark you down for having SQLi in your code, because when you graduate, SQLi is a HUGE business risk for whomever you end up working for.

Comment: @НадеждаТарашкевич: It absolutely does - but it's not a method call as per your comment. It's a property assignment, assigning the `Value` property in the just-added parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The cast of the ExecuteScalar works if your SQL query is retrieving a count of rows and not the column data. The returned count from SQL is then being cast to an int in C#.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).